# Link location on Ionic 3

Tags: google-maps, ionic3

I need to create a href inside my ion-fab and link to a certain position of google maps, I wonder if this is possible in ionic 3?

This is my `home-condominios.ts`

```
  <img [src]="property?.imagem">
    <ion-fab right top>
      <button ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="pin"><a href="{{property.localizacao}}"></a></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-fab>
```

And this is my `condominios.ts`

```
initializeItems(){
  this.items = [
    {id: '1', nome:'ACQUALINA', rua:'Paraguassu', cidade:'Xangri-lá', bairro:'Xangri-lá', numero:'130', localizcao: 'https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Condom%C3%ADnio+Acqualina/@-29.8284344,-50.0542912,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xe64c7f1670c62f72?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAy8rM1Y7eAhXDHpAKHYeaD20Q_BIwFHoECAsQCw' , imagem:'assets/logos/ACQUALINA.jpg'},
  ];
}
```

Note that I'm defining the location within my array of objects

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the following

```
 <img [src]="property?.imagem">
    <ion-fab right top>
        <a href="{{property.localizacao}}" target="_system"><button ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon>
      </button></a>
    </ion-fab>
```